# How can buttermilk marinade for raw chicken be used afterwards?

Tags: culinary-uses, marinade, buttermilk

[Other](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/38090/reusing-marinade-just-used-for-raw-chicken) [questions](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/1297/can-you-reuse-marinade-used-with-raw-chicken) here ask about *reusing* chicken marinade. My question is not about reuse for a second batch but about options for using the leftover marinade immediately for another cooking purpose.

I've [read](https://www.gardenweb.com/discussions/2464548/reuse-buttermilk) [comments](https://www.reddit.com/r/Cooking/comments/howwg/what_to_do_with_buttermilk_from_marinade/) elsewhere that this cannot be done due to food safety. However, these comments seem to reflect gut feelings and are not scientifically grounded. Sufficient heat kills bacteria in the leftover buttermilk just as it does in the chicken that is to be cooked. But if you think otherwise, please reference science in your answer.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know about buttermilk marinade.

You can reuse marinade used for meat if you cook/boil it enough to kill bacterias.

https://www.thespruceeats.com/making-marinades-safe-331649

"The most effective way to kill the germs and make the marinade safe to eat is to boil it. This is an approved suggestion according to the USDA's food safety guidelines.​​​"

https://ask.usda.gov/s/article/Can-you-reuse-meat-marinade

"If some of the marinade is to be used as a sauce on the cooked food, reserve a portion of the marinade before putting raw meat or poultry in it. However, if the marinade used on raw meat or poultry is to be reused, **make sure to let it come to a boil first to destroy any harmful bacteria**."

Comment: If you need to wash your hands everytime you touch raw chicken I don't see how using a sauce that has touched raw chicken for hours again is a good idea. I don't know why the marinade is not just used in the cooking process as well.

Comment: @NeilMeyer you can't bring your hands to a boil ;)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest, for buttermilk specifically, to make it into a cheese sauce by reducing down the marinade a bit to kill the bacteria and then add some grated cheese.

Comment: Welcome! Answering „old“ questions is perfectly fine, no need to explain. That’s why we usually take out all non-answer parts, trying to keep the content concise and clear.